# How do I make my code return to original question? Could someone please fix my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I just have a small issue with my code
I defined my response = ""
I tried to make it so that it would bring me back to my shop menu!!
But it is not working!
Could someone please be kind enough to fix this entire code for me?
Thank you so much!!!!!

My code:

```
CharacterHealth = 100
import time
Coins = 1000
Sword = ["Diamond", "Metal", "Wood"]
Shop = ["Shop"]







print("Hello! Welcome to my game! This is an extremely fun action game! I hope you enjoy!\n")
time.sleep(2)
name = input("Please enter your username.\nUsername: \033[1;32;40m")
print("\033[1;37;40mHello, " + name + ". Would you like to enter a shop?\nYou can purchase 
swords!\n")
time.sleep(2)




response = ""
while response not in Shop:
response = input("Would you like to enter the shop?(yes/no)\nSelection: \033[1;32;40m")

if (response == "Yes") or (response == "yes"):
answer = input("\n\033[1;37;40mYou have 1000 coins. Would you like to buy:\n(a) Diamond sword 
[Costs 900]\n(b) Metal Sword [500]\n(c) Wooden sword [200]\n(d) Back\nSelection: \033[1;32;40m")
if (answer == "A") or (answer == "a"):
  Coins = 1000 - 900
  response = input(name + "\033[1;37;40m, you currently have " + str(Coins) + " Coins!")
  response = ""

if (answer == "B") or (answer == "b"):
   Coins = 1000 - 500
   response = input(name + "\033[1;37;40m, you currently have " + str(Coins) + " Coins!")
   response = ""

if (answer == "C") or (answer == "c"):
    Coins = 1000 - 200
    response = input(name + "\033[1;37;40m, you currently have " + str(Coins) + " Coins!")
    response = ""
        

if (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
 print("You exit the shop.\n")
 time.sleep(2)
 response = ""


 if (response == "No") or (response == "no"):
   print("You exit the shop.")
   print("You enter your house.")
```

Thank you guys so much! I hope one of you could fix my code!!
(You can paste it into replit.com or pycharm to fix it)

Comment: what do you mean by its not working? do you get an error or it just wont ask you for input?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help you and give you a appropriate start for further coding. If you need any explanation don´t hesitate to ask.

You should consider that you add a routine that you cannot buy more swords if you ran out of coins.

```py
import time


def coins_left(player_name, coins):
    print(player_name + "\033[1;37;40m, you currently have " + str(coins) + " Coins!")

def exit_shop_house():
   print("You exit the shop.\n")
   print("You enter your house.")
CharacterHealth = 100
Coins = 1000
Sword = ["Diamond", "Metal", "Wood"]
Shop = ["Shop"]

print("Hello! Welcome to my game! This is an extremely fun action game! I hope you enjoy!\n")
time.sleep(2)
name = input("Please enter your username.\nUsername: \033[1;32;40m")
print("\033[1;37;40mHello, " + name + ". Would you like to enter a shop?\nYou can purchase swords!\n")
time.sleep(2)

response = input("Would you like to enter the shop?(yes/no)\nSelection: \033[1;32;40m")
if (response == "Yes") or (response == "yes"):

    while True:
        answer = input("\n\033[1;37;40mYou have %s coins. Would you like to buy:\n(a) Diamond sword [Costs 900]\n(b) Metal Sword[500]\n(c) Wooden sword[200]\n(d) Back\nSelection: \033[1; 32; 40 m" % Coins)
        if (answer == "A") or (answer == "a"):
            Coins -= 900
            coins_left(name, Coins)
        elif (answer == "B") or (answer == "b"):
            Coins -= 500
            coins_left(name, Coins)
        elif (answer == "C") or (answer == "c"):
            Coins -= 200
            coins_left(name, Coins)
        elif (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
            exit_shop_house()
            time.sleep(2)
            break
else:
    exit_shop_house()
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for helping me!! I used your code, and have just one issue. If you answer D (to exit the shop) it ends the code. How would I make it so that it would go to the else statement


else:
    print("You exit the shop.")
    print("You enter your house.")


Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Karthikeya Arikirevula You cannot jump to `else` after breaking the loop if you enter if-condition. I edited the code. What you could do you can call a methode like `exit_shop_house()` that will be called in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (response == "Yes") or (response == "yes"):
```

you should go:

```
response= response.lower()

if(response == "yes"):
```

*Because if user answers YES, Yes, yEs an so on your program will get confused and less errors when you forgot something*

Comment: I posted another question here!! Please help!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051816/how-do-i-make-my-code-return-outside-loop-could-someone-please-fix-my-code