# How do I make my code return outside loop? Could someone please fix my code?

Tags: python

I hope you are doing well!
I am making a code for my free time.
I just have a small issue with it.
After you buy a sword in my game, I put "break" so that it brings you to the else statement.

(Just put my code into a console such as replit or pycharm and you will understand)

But when I put my break, it ends my code!
I would want it to instead write everything after this part:

else:

print("\033[1;37;40mYou exit the shop.")

print("After leaving the shop, you head home.")

Here is my code:

```
import time


def coins_left(player_name, coins):
  print(player_name + "\033[1;37;40m, you currently have " + str(coins) + " Coins!")


CharacterHealth = 100
Coins = 1000
Sword = "Diamond" or "Metal" or "Wooden"
Shop = ["Shop"]

print("Hello! Welcome to my game! This is an extremely fun action game! I hope you enjoy!\n")
time.sleep(2)
name = input("Please enter your username.\nUsername: \033[1;32;40m")

response = input("\033[1;37;40mHello, " + name + ". Would you like to enter the shop?(yes/no)\nSelection: \033[1;32;40m")
if (response == "Yes") or (response == "yes"):

 while True:
    answer = input("\n\033[1;37;40mYou have %s coins. Would you like to buy:\n(a) Diamond sword [Costs 900]\n(b) Metal Sword[500]\n(c) Wooden sword[200]\n(d) Back\nSelection: \033[1; 32; 40 m" % Coins)
    if (answer == "A") or (answer == "a"):
      Sword = "Diamond"
      print(name + ", you have bought a " + str(Sword) + " Sword!")
      Coins -= 900
      coins_left(name, Coins)
      break
    elif (answer == "B") or (answer == "b"):
        Sword = "Metal"
        print(name + ", you have bought a " + str(Sword) + " Sword!")
        Coins -= 500
        coins_left(name, Coins)
        break
    elif (answer == "C") or (answer == "c"):
        print(name + ", you have bought a " + str(Sword) + " Sword!")
        Coins -= 200
        coins_left(name, Coins)
        break
    elif (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
        print("You exit the shop.\n")
        break
        
else:
    print("\033[1;37;40mYou exit the shop.")
    print("After leaving the shop, you head home.")
```

Thank you so much for helping me through this process! I hope you can fix this!

**Have a great day!**

Comment: If you want the while loop to continue, just remove the `break`.

Comment: `Sword = "Diamond" or "Metal" or "Wooden"`  - it doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @Marat Actually, I don't think I understand what that is *intended* to do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how `if-else` statements works. Since your print statements are inside the `else` statement they will only execute if the user had entered "yes" or "Yes". If you want the print statements to execute only if the user had entered anything else, this would work as expected.

However, if you simply want them to be run whenever they "leave" or don't enter the shop you can simply leave them outside any conditional, or even add a `boolean` value to make sure that they actually entered the shop beforehand:

```py
shop_entered = False

if (response == "Yes") or (response == "yes"):
    shop_entered = True

    # do shop things...
        
if shop_entered:
  print("\033[1;37;40mYou exit the shop.")
  print("After leaving the shop, you head home.")
```

When you `break` your loop you are telling the program to stop the loop and execute the code following the loop; however, since there is no code following the loop, the `if` branch of the conditional is finished, and  python will execute anything following the conditional (in this case anything that follows the `else`). Since there is no other code, your program exits without any more code being run.

If you add a print statement at then end or your script, something like `print("thanks for playing!")`, you will see "thanks for playing!" printed to the console after everything else is run.